# How can I send the file and formdata in aiohttp in Python?

Tags: python, aiohttp

I am having an use case to send files and the other formdata that is being received from client (front-end/postman) to a file-upload service to upload the file. For this, I am using `aiohttp`. I am facing a couple of issues when sending it in the request body.

```py
# View

from fastapi import APIRouter, Request
from app.services.file_upload_service import FileUploadClient

file_upload_router = APIRouter(prefix="/file_upload")


@file_upload_router.post("/")
async def upload_files(request: Request):
    req = await request.form()
    file = req._dict.get("file") # type --> <class 'tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile'>
    response = await FileUploadClient.upload_file(file)
    return Response(...)
```

```py
# util

class FileUploadClient(someClass):
    ...

    ...

    @classmethod
    async def upload_file(cls, file):
        if not file:
            return None

        url = "endpoint_to_file_upload_service"
        file_name = file.filename
        data_dict = {'file_name': file_name, 'form_data_key1': 'val1', 'form_data_key2': 'val2'}
        formdata = aiohttp.FormData()
        for key, value in data_dict.items():
            formdata.add_field(key, value)
        formdata.add_field('file', file.file)
        print(type(file.file))
        auth = await cls.get_auth() # This is BasicAuth: aiohttp.BasicAuth(username, password)
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.request("post", url, data=formdata, auth=auth, timeout=5) as response:
                resp = await response.json()
                print(resp)
                return resp
```

This throws error: `{'detail': 'Unsupported media type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" in request.'}`
when keeping headers as NULL,

and when sending `application/json` in header as `content-type` it is throwing `{'detail': 'Unsupported media type "application/json" in request.'}`

When I'm sending the same header that is being received from the client, then the above issues disappear, but the body is received as an empty body in the file upload service.

How can I fix this?